# Row Updating event of Gridview is not working properly, get old values instead of new values when updating

Tags: c#, gridview

My `Gridview` contains many template fields which includes label box, image button, button, file upload controls. when I go edit row in `gridview`, and give new value by changing the old value, then I go to click the update button, there was no error will be thrown. When I put break point and debug line by line, it only takes old value not a new value.

The code was given below:
[image: My Code]

Comment: An interesting approach to the publication of the code. It would be even better if you shoot video from your monitor with the code...